# GAE - Domain Verification producing error

Tags: google-app-engine, appdomainsetup

I have been adding domains to apps without any issues for past couple months, following these instructions https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/domains

Since past two days I have not been able to, when clicking Activate this service I get this error message "An error occurred while trying to install this application. Please try again later."

I have tried this also with older domains and with different apps and getting the same error, so the problem seems to be more widespread, not isolated to particular domains / apps.

Does anyone know how to solve?

Comment: Are you still dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem on Google's end; it's not just you.  I've filed a ticket with them for myself and am waiting to hear back.  Your options are to:

1. [File a ticket with them yourself](http://contact.googleapps.com/), or
2. Do nothing, trusting that they'll fix it soon.

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be anything we can do from our end to resolve the issue.